# How to solve $\int _{\frac{\pi }{8}}^{\frac{\pi }{3}}\frac{dx}{1+\left( \tan x\right) ^{\sqrt{2}}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Calculate $$\int _{\pi/8}^{3\pi/8}\dfrac{dx}{1+\left( \tan x\right) ^{\sqrt{2}}}\,.$$

I thought.

If I put $t=\tan x$, it becomes $dx=\cos ^{2}xdt$ and $x$ remains.
So I can do integration by substitution.

And I thought that rationalize the denominator but I can't do.

Comment: Interesting limits of integration. Can you explain them?

Comment: In other words, $dx=dt/(1+t^2)$. Incidentally, this problem would be easy if the limits were instead $0,\,\pi/2$, which may be why @Integrand asked about the limits you gave.

Comment: Wow, i'd be amazed if this has a nice solution

Comment: @J.G. Or $\pi/6$ instead of $\pi/8$, which I think is a more plausible writo.

Comment: @user10354138 Well-spotted! Any positive limits summing to $\pi/2$ would do.

Comment: Can you provide the source to this problem?

Comment: According to Wolfram Alpha, the result is approximately 0.3575.  Considering the WA doesn't have an exact form for the integral, my guess is that it can't be solved analytically

Comment: @Moko19 I agree here for this integral, but there are many examples of definite integrals that can be solved analytically where Wolfram can't compute it.

Comment: Even changing the lower limit to the perhaps more reasonable $\frac{\pi}{6}$ didn't lead to a closed form. Interestingly, the plot gives an approximate trapezoid in Wolfram Alpha. I wonder if this was meant to be an approximation and not exact answer. This function is a pretty good approximation of a saw tooth wave.

Comment: @CameronWilliams what everyone above is saying is that if the limit were $\frac{\pi}{6}$ then the answer of $\frac{\pi}{12}$ is easily retrieved by symmetry. This is exactly an example of what Ty was talking about where Wolfram didn't compute the answer but it can be analytically solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*This problem looks to be a trap.*

If you look at the integrand in the range of integration, it is almost a straight line.

Expanding as a Taylor series around $x=\frac \pi 4$ (almost the middle of the interval), we have (I wrote a lot of terms knowing that most of them will not have any impact of the result)
$$\dfrac{1}{1+\left( \tan (x)\right) ^{\sqrt{2}}}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\left(x-\frac{\pi }{4}\right)+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{15} 
   \left(x-\frac{\pi }{4}\right)^5+\frac{16\sqrt{2}}{315}  \left(x-\frac{\pi
   }{4}\right)^7+\frac{13\sqrt{2}}{405}  \left(x-\frac{\pi }{4}\right)^9+$$ $$\frac{736
   \sqrt{2} }{31185}\left(x-\frac{\pi }{4}\right)^{11}+\frac{135098 \sqrt{2}}{6081075}\left(x-\frac{\pi }{4}\right)^{13}+O\left(\left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)^{15}\right)$$
On the other side
$$\int _{\frac\pi 8}^{\frac\pi3} \left(x-\frac{\pi }{4}\right)^{2n+1}\, dx=\frac{ \left(\left(\frac{4}{9}\right)^{n+1}-1\right) \pi ^{2 n+2}}{2^{6 n+7}(n+1)}$$ Cumulating these terms and converting them to decimals, we have the following results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 0.3272492347 \\
 0.3575394439 \\
 0.3574868754 \\
 0.3574819953 \\
 0.3574816063 \\
 0.3574815691 \\
 0.3574815645 \\
 0.3574815638
\end{array}
\right)$$ while numerical integration would give $0.3574815637$.

We can have a "nice looking" approximation builging the $[4,4]$ Padé approximant of the integrand

$$\dfrac{1}{1+\left( \tan (x)\right) ^{\sqrt{2}}}\sim\frac{\frac 12 + \sum_{m=1}^4 a_m \left(x-\frac{\pi }{4}\right)^m}{1+ \sum_{m=1}^4 b_m \left(x-\frac{\pi }{4}\right)^m }$$ where the $a_m$ are
$$\left\{-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},-\frac{8}{21},\frac{8 \sqrt{2}}{21},\frac{1}{15}\right\}$$ and the $b_m$ are
$$\left\{0,-\frac{16}{21},0,\frac{2}{15}\right\}$$ Using partial fraction decomposition we end with
$$\int _{\frac\pi 8}^{\frac\pi3}\dfrac{dx}{1+\left( \tan (x)\right) ^{\sqrt{2}}}=\frac{5 \pi }{48}-\frac{173}{28} \sqrt{\frac{5}{13}} \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{40
   \sqrt{130} \pi ^2}{483840-4160 \pi ^2+7 \pi ^4}\right)-$$ $$\frac{10\sqrt{2}}{7} 
   \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{1600 \left(\pi ^2-273\right)}{651840-4160 \pi ^2+7 \pi
   ^4}\right)-\frac{40}{7} \sqrt{2} \coth ^{-1}(5)$$ which is $0.3574816071$.

Answer (score -2):

**As per the suggestion of @J.G the lower limit needs to be $\pi/6$, otherwise it is not doable by hand**

Use the property that $$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx=\int_{a}^{b} f(a+b-x) dx.~~~~(1)$$
$$I=\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/3} \frac{1}{1+\tan^{\sqrt{2}}x} dx~~~~(2)$$
Using (1), we get
$$I=\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/3} \frac{1}{1+\tan^{\sqrt{2}}(\pi/2-x)} dx=\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/3} \frac{1}{1+\cot^{\sqrt{2}}x} dx~~~~(2)$$
adding (2) and (3), we get
$$2I=\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/3} \left(\frac{1}{1+\tan^{\sqrt{2}}x}+\frac{1}{1+\cot^{\sqrt{2}}x}\right)dx=\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/3} 1 dx=\pi/6$$
$$\implies I=\pi/12$$